# System unit configuration. What does 3/3/3 mean?

Tags: desktop-computer

If I choose an HP Compaq and I have the following configuration:

`dc7700 CMT E4400 160G FDD DVDRW 1G XP Pro Office Ready 3/3/3`.

What do the digits 3/3/3 mean?  There can also be 3/3/0, 2/2/0, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It refer to warranty information. For example 3-3-3. The first digit means you have 3 years "parts" warranty. The second digit means you have 3 years "labor" warranty and the last digit means you have 3 years onsite service.

Comment: Yeah! I got it at official HP site.

Answer (score 1):

This means **3 years** parts, **3 years** labor, **3 years** onsite service (a technician will come to your location to replace parts if necessary), in that order.

This would be written on your system's chassis or serial number label as "Warranty: 3y3y3y".

Unless purchased with an optional Care Pack, most consumer HP systems sold in the US have a "1y1y0y" warranty,  meaning one year parts and labor and no onsite service.